# Mongoose 10ms to query a single, tiny document on localhost?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Mongoose: **4.13.15**

MongoDB: **3.4**

I have a local database with a collection with one document:
`{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b7e3003b1227c1e1889d650"),
  "test" : "something!"
}`

I am querying it in node:

```
const mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});
```

...

```
console.time('timing test.');
const user = await User.findOne({});
console.timeEnd('timing test.');
```

Response:
`timing test.: 10.298ms`
Is there any reason why I should be receiving 10ms response times?
That seems crazy high?

I'm basically asking what could cause this issue?  The query should be nearly instantaneous, no?

Comment: Is every request so slow or just the first one? What happens if you do one after the other `await User.findOne({})`?

Comment: Right, the first one would also include the initial connect time.

Comment: Use `lean` before `exec`.

Comment: I have executed this code in a new project where no others tasks was running at same time. Measured with process.hrtime() the result is an average of 2.5ms on 10 query executed if i exclude the first query and 3.2ms if i include the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Akrion and @JohnnyHK and @Daniele Tassone
It does look like the initial connection was causing a bit of a delay.

If anyone else comes across this, it may be that your first query takes slightly longer due to opening that initial query connection.  I believe this is the case, so I'll leave this as the answer.